# Collisions between texts and rectangles in js

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

I'm trying to create a game where a car crashes into letters, how can I create these collisions? Because I only know how to create collisions between rectangles or circles, but not between letters. I tried both creating some writing and using PNG images with the writing inside but I didn't find the solution. Thanks in advance!

If I create the writings directly with HTML canvas, then I have created a function that manages the collisions, but I cannot switch between the writings, because it is as if it treats them all as a single block.

Comment: If you dont require pixel perfect collision, you can spawn the letters inside shapes (rectangles/circles) and check the car collision between them. Also you could save the letters as images and then set them as `background-image` of those shapes.

Comment: try taking a look to canvas.measureText()

Comment: the problem is that I need pixel perfect collision, because otherwise it is not realistic because the car would not touch the letters but the square.

Comment: Then if you're making a game in js and you want pixel perfect collision why not use a game engine like https://phaser.io/ ? It would save you time making stuff from scratch.